# Unsure of this sentence; lack of verb is throwing me off here

Tags: grammar, meaning, verbs, parsing

I can't properly understand this sentence

> そして, そのマントは 他人には決して見えないことを, 彼女たちは知っていた.

I think it means:

And the girls knew, those cloaks (would reveal/showed) to strangers something they've never seen? And those cloaks (showed) something to strangers the girls knew they've never seen?

I want to understand this thoroughly. The lack of any verb in the first phrase is really throwing me off.

Comment: This sentence has actually three verbs 見える, 知る, and いる.

Answer (score 3):

マントは見えない : The cloak is invisible.

Probably, this resolves your problem.

Overall, "And, they knew that the cloak was definitely invisible to others."